# apt-get upgrade doesn't upgrade bash --- so why the bash reinstallation is an upgrade?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, upgrade, software-installation

`apt-get upgrade` doesn't upgrade bash from 4.3 to 4.4. Thus it seems from `bash --version`),

so why the bash reinstallation is an upgrade?

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade bash
```

Or it's just a weird terminology for saying "reinstall only Bash".

Comment: This is not very clear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I desire to upgrade Bash from bash 4.3 to 4.4...

Comment: Oh, you'll have to do that manually, though Ubuntu 17.04 and newer versions have it built in.

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to upgrade to bash 4.4? Can it wait til end of april 2018? ;P

Comment: If it's not in the repositories for your Ubuntu version, it won't get upgraded. Either upgrade the OS, or build newer bash from source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check what upgrades that can be expected with the following command

```
apt-cache policy bash
```

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and the output is

```
bash:
  Installed: 4.3-14ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 4.3-14ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 4.3-14ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.3-14ubuntu1 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

In other words, there is no newer version of `bash` in the repository for 16.04 alias xenial. This is the reason why it will not be upgraded.

Normally there is **no** reason to upgrade a program package in a case like this, but it is possible, if you can find a newer version, for example via a PPA.

Answer (score 3):

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade <package>
```

doesn't reinstall a package, it just upgrades only the specified package and only if it is installed, see `man apt-get`:

> `--only-upgrade`
>                                                                                                        Do not install new packages; when used in conjunction with `install`,
>   only-upgrade will install upgrades for already installed packages only
>   and ignore requests to install new packages.

As [the Xenial repositories only ship bash 4.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bash) it won't get updated by `apt`. Sure you could install bash 4.4 manually, but it's not a good idea at all to fiddle with a core program as essential as bash.

If you really need to upgrade bash I recommend the following approach:

```
sudo at 27.04.2018 update-manager --proposed
```

This will upgrade your system to [Ubuntu 18.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule) on April 27, 2018 
 and on the way update bash to version 4.4-5. Of course I'm not entirely serious here, but updating Ubuntu is actually the way to go if you urgently need bash 4.4.

Comment: Please see my edit --- why then, not doing `apt-get upgrade --only-upgrade XYZ`? Also, bash doesn't get upgraded from 4.3 to 4.4 with `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: @dessert make that comment part of your answer. That's the essential part. If newer version not in repositories - it  won't get upgraded

Comment: Only 138 days left!

Comment: I thank you dessert, for coming to my aid. Given my Ubuntu 16.04 xenial Nginx server environment is minimal (no kernel/shell/utility customizations), what do you think of me upgrading the whole OS to Ubuntu 17.04, instead waiting to April 2018? I have a backup for my website so even if the unlikely happens and a data loss occured, I still have a local backup (will double check that just in principle). Please edit regarding this. I'll gladly give you a bounty as well.